# QGis missing osgeo python-gdal, Python 27 vs Python 36

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, installation, windows

I have trouble while installing QGis from scratch on a computer that already have Python (3.4) + GDAL bindings. Here, QGis works with Python27, that needs its own GDAL bindings : how can i deal with this ? When i install a parallel version of GDAL, with a new GDAL_DRIVER_PATH, new Python27 paths etc... it breaks my Python36 install. It does that for any version of QGis...

Do you have any advice for that?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72456/qgis-2-0-plugin-error-unable-to-load-gdaltools-plugin , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/how-to-fix-unable-to-load-gdaltools-plugin-the-required-osgeo-python-gdal

Comment: I think @FranciscoRaga is right but can you edit your question to include what operating system you are on and your install method.